# Log field in Transaction reciep

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, quorum

I want to set some data in the Log field in a transaction using Ethereum,
i used in smart contract event method but i got always empty logs could anyone help me please?
Thank you

Comment: your question is unclear, what code did you use to generate the event, and what do you mean by log field? please elaborate more.

Comment: When you retrieve logs the request usually take about 5 to 10 seconds on testnet. Also posting your code should be helpful.

Comment: @BadrBellaj log column in a transaction body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transaction's receipt is only generated if the transaction ends in success. If the transaction ran out of gas or threw an exception, the receipt will not be generated. The first thing I would check is that the transaction ended without error.

If the transaction ended successfully, then the next most likely cause of no log would be that you're querying the node incorrectly.

As mentioned, in either case, example code would help come up with a better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much !! and how i can add some logs when the transaction ends in success please?

Comment: In your Solidity code, you first must define an event, and then wherever you want that log to appear, you call it in your functions.